# I am using a triac bta41-600b with MOC3083, doesn't work

Tags: switches, mains, triac

I have used the circuit from Datasheet of MOC3083 directly. Problem is triac does not fire. 0.1uF cap is MPF and all the values given in data sheet are used as they are. I am using a 100W incandescent Bulb as load. I have connected 2 AA batteries as input to phototriac.
[image: Just Change the Phototriac to MOC3083]

All the resistors are 1/4 watt standard. This is my first shot at triacs kindly help.

Comment: That looks like a circuit for a MOC3041 not a 3083. Also what is Rin and what AC supply are you using?

Comment: I AM USING MAINS 220V Rin is 470E but i have used 1.5KE as well. But I have used MOC3083 as could not find MOC3041 here locally.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The trigger current required to cause the output of the MOC3083 to work is 5mA according to the data sheet. You are using two AA batteries giving a voltage of 3V (I assume). The forward volt drop of the LED is 1.5 volts therefore, with a 470 ohm resistor, the current you are injecting into the LED is 3.2 mA and lower than the 5mA recommended. I'm not saying this is the cause but a possible cause.

Comment: I switched it to 1.5K as well but, it did not work. Should I use a 9V battery instead.

Comment: 1k5 will be even smaller current. You need to ensure that at least 5mA flows.

Comment: How about a 9v battery? or 5V DC supply

Comment: With the appropriate value resistor yes.

Comment: Is firing of triac dependent on Load values. I would say "no" but, still want to ask. What should be appropriate resistor for 5V dc supply?

Comment: I can't keep answering ad hoc questions due to time constraints. Use ohms law to calculate resistors so, if supply is 5V, the effective supply is about 3.5 volts due to inherent blocking voltage of LED so to get 30mA (probably best to go for the recommended value) the ohms are 3.5/0.03 = 116 ohms so make it a 120 ohm.

Comment: Thanks Andy I am going to try this now. Will post here if I have another problem. I am a "noob" at this I am a trained programmer but Electrics do scare me to the core. I am just trying to experiment with this as a hobby offshoot.

Comment: I tried connecting it directly to 3v. I worked:).

Comment: Be careful because you can easily damage an LED with too much forward voltage without a current limit resistor.

Comment: My resistors are now heap of ash. what value should I use? I am talking about 330 and 360E. They were 1/4W. They burnt as soon as the bulb turned on. What to do?

Comment: I calculated it would leave 1.5V to drop and I will introduce an led in series to check that.

Comment: I think you'll need to read the data sheet and track down any recommendations they say.

Comment: Andy my dear, "they" didn't say anything. But a lot of thanks and wishes for you lad

Answer (score -1):

You need signal voltage to trigger the MOC, not 220 V. It may be the possible cause of not working.

Comment: Welcome to EE.SE, Ojo. Did you notice that Andy's answer was accepted as correct fou years ago?